# compare a wordlist with itself based on first 4 characters

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file that looks something like this...

```
testing
tested
tests
answer
questioned
questions
ask
run
running
```

I need to find the words where first 4 characters are the same and if the count of such words is more than 2. The expected result is

```
testing
tested
tests
```

This code works if the file has a few words. Takes a lot of time for larger input files.

```
from collections import Counter
mylist=list()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        mylist.append(i[:4])
myn=Counter(mylist)

import pandas as pd
mys=pd.Series(myn)
myindex=list(mys[mys > 2].index)

newlist=list()

for x in myindex:
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
        for i in f.readlines():
            if x ==  i[:4]:
                newlist.append(i)
```

Is there a better way to achive the same results?

Comment: If a 5-char word appears twice in the input -  does it get counted twice or just once? Does it get printed twice in the output?

Comment: Words are unique in the input file @EdMorton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
{
     n = substr($0,1,4);
     c[n]++;
     w[n] = (length(w[n]) ? w[n]"\n" : "") $0
}
END{ for (n in c) if (c[n] > 2) print w[n] }'
```

- `n=substr...` - extract first 4 characters - it's our index
- `c[n]++` - keep the count
- `w[n]=...` - remember the words, separated by newlines
- `for(n in c)if(c[n]>2)print w[n]` - for each word, if the count is greater then 2, print the word.

Answer (score 1):

The main bottleneck of the code is that you are reading the file two times. In the case of large files, the end result is that you will take at least double the time.

If you can afford to hold in memory the whole contents of the file I would do something along the lines of: (A previous answer already proposes this but using a defaultdict)

```
Words = dict()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as File:
    for line in File:
        key = line[:4]
        if Words[key]:
            Words[key].append(line)
        else:
            Words[key] = [line,]
Output = []
for key,items in Words.items():
    if len(items) > 2: 
        Output.extend(items)
```

In case you can't hold in memory the contents you are forced to read the file a second time, so one option is to store the line number in the dictionary and on a second read print only the stored line numbers:

```
Words = dict()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as File:
    for i,line in enumerate(File):
        key = line[:4]
        if Words[key]:
            Words[key].append(i)
        else:
            Words[key] = [i,]
LineNumbers = set()
for key,items in Words.items():
    if len(items) > 2: 
        LineNumbers.update(items)
Output = []
with open('test.txt', 'r') as File:
    for i,line in enumerate(File):
        if i in LineNumbers:
            Output.append(line)
```

Note: If you call the File.readlines() you are already holding in memory the contents of the file in a list during the iteration the lifetime of the for loop. If you iterate by line using "for line in File" I think that the iteration is done  by reading the line on demand.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for arrays of arrays and assuming you want a count of unique words:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    key = substr($0,1,4)
    words[key][$0]
}
END {
    for ( key in words ) {
        if ( length(words[key]) > 2 ) {
            for ( word in words[key] ) {
                print word
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
tested
tests
testing
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to bin the lines of your input file to a dictionary with the first 4 letters as a key and a list of lines as values.
Something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
binned_lines = defaultdict{lambda: list()}
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        binned_lines[line[:4]] = binned_lines[line[:4]].append(line)

for key, lines in binned_lines.items():
    if len(lines) > 2:
        print(lines)
```

Should save you all the indexing and only needs to open the file once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be done faster using *comprehensions* following way, let `test.txt` content be:

```
testing
tested
tests
answer
questioned
questions
ask
run
running
```

and `morethan2.py` content

```
from collections import Counter
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
myn=Counter(i[:4] for i in lines)
newlist=[i for i in lines if myn[i[:4]]>2]
print(newlist)
```

then `python3 morethan2.py` output

```
['testing\n', 'tested\n', 'tests\n']
```

Explanation: `f.readlines()` return list of lines, I save that it as `lines`. Then I use comprehension as `Counter` argument (`collections.Counter` accept any iterable, not only `list`) then I use `list` comprehension with condition to pick only elements whose 4 letters appeared more than 2 times. Note that `collections.Counter` instance behaves like `dict` with values being number of occurences. Finally I `print` newlines, note that `.readlines` does keep trailing endlines by default, hence `\n`s.